# Merge with multiple primary keys

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge, primary-key

I have 2 columns that makes a record unique, so I want to merge with multiple keys. How can I do this?

I tried this but it doesnt seem to work:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 AS DST
USING TABLE2 AS SRC
ON SRC.pk1 = DST.pk1 
AND
SRC.pk2 = DST.pk2 

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (pk1, pk2, Description)
VALUES (SRC.p1, SRC.pk2, SRC.Description)
;
```

Comment: What you have here will insert rows from `table2` to `table1`. Except for a typo in the values clause you have it. Change `SRC.p1` to `SRC.pk1`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson answer that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have here will insert rows from `table2` to `table1`. Except for a typo in the values clause you have it. Change `SRC.p1` to `SRC.pk1`.

Try here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120421/